# .doc file is created but styles and colours are not applying in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument

Im Creating .doc file but its creating with only string , no designs are applying . just simple string coming in .doc file

```
  System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        System.Xml.XmlDocument dom = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        design.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        string strBuilder = stringWrite.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;");
        System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(strBuilder);
        string rawText = xmlDoc.InnerText;
        string strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Temp\\WeeklyReport of " + Projname + ".doc";
        var doc = DocX.Create(strPath,DocumentTypes.Document);
        doc.InsertParagraph(rawText);
        doc.Save();
```

Comment: What kind of styles do you want to apply to this document?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/mr1h2z4mv/

click here to see this image which i need in doc, but im getting below doc style

http://postimg.org/image/jo4nesli5/